# Web app for converting video files, mpeg, wmv, avi to flv?

Tags: webapp-rec, video

Is there any web app, where I can upload videos (formats: `wmv, mpeg, avi, 3gp` etc) to `flv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Media Convert**](http://media-convert.com/) supports lots of formats and 100% free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Zamzar](http://zamzar.com/) is a free online file conversion service that let's you convert files from a variety of video formats to FLV.

You can either upload (upto 100MB for free) a file or submit a URL